# What do these "it"s in "Women in the Nineteenth Century" refer to?

Tags: pronouns

Here's an excerpt from *Women in the Nineteenth Century*:

> Sages and lawgivers have bent their whole nature to the search for truth, and thought themselves happy if they could buy, with the sacrifice of all temporal ease and pleasure, one seed for the future Eden. Poets and priests have strung the lyre with the heart-strings, poured out their best blood upon the altar, which, reared anew from age to age, shall at last sustain the flame pure enough to rise to highest heaven. Shall we not name with as deep a benediction those who, if not so immediately, or so consciously, in connection with the eternal truth, yet, led and fashioned by a divine instinct, serve no less to develop and interpret the open secret of love passing into life, energy creating for the purpose of happiness; the artist whose hand, drawn by a preexistent harmony to a certain medium, moulds ***it*** to forms of life more highly and completely organized than are seen elsewhere, and, by carrying out the intention of nature, reveals her meaning to those who are not yet wise enough to divine ***it***; the philosopher who listens steadily for laws and causes, and from those obvious infers those yet unknown; the historian who, in faith that all events must have their reason and their aim, records them, and thus fills archives from which the youth of prophets may be fed; the man of science dissecting the statements, testing the facts and demonstrating order, even where he cannot its purpose?

I wanna know, what do the two "it"s refer to separately?

Comment: The artist moulds the *medium* and informs those who have not divined *her [ie, nature's] meaning*.

Comment: @StoneyB Many thanks! Would you also tell me whose purpose does the last "its purpose" refer to?

Comment: He cannot demonstrate the purpose of *order*.

Answer (score 0):

> the artist whose hand, drawn by a preexistent harmony to a certain medium, moulds **it**

it refers to the "different *mediums*"

> reveals her meaning to those who are not yet wise enough to divine **it**

**it** refers to the "*artist's meaning*" and by extension "*the intention of nature*"